# How can i access object inside array of object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have control Owners json object so i am trying to get worker from it , How can i assign worker json object to `$scope.controlOwnerObj.worker` ?

ctrl.js

```
if ($state.is('app.editControl')) {
          angular.forEach($scope.controlDTO.controlOwners,function(owner){
            $scope.selectedOwners = owner 
          })
         // $scope.selectedOwners = $scope.controlDTO.controlOwners[0].worker;
//        $scope.controlDTO.controlOwners[0].worker.fullName;
          console.log('EDIT CONTROL OWNERS DATA', $scope.selectedOwners);
        }
```

json.js

```
"controlOwners": [{
    "worker": {
        "workerKey": -1093,
        "sourceFeed": null,
        "statusLookUpCode": null,
        "externalId": null,
        "createdUserText": null,
        "createdTimestamp": null,
        "modifiedUserText": null,
        "modifiedTimestamp": null,
        "stdId": "ZK84T1N",
        "ccId": null,
        "empClasId": null,
        "deptId": null,
        "fullName": "Rajasekaran, Shanmuga",
    }
}],
```

Answer (score 3):

Specify the array index you want:

```
$scope.controlOwnerObj.worker = $scope.controlOwners[0].worker;
```

Comment: how about if i want to display list of workers then index will not work in that case correct ?

Comment: Then you iterate over the array, `angular.forEach()` or `Array#forEach`

Comment: i am new to angularJS i added angular.forEach code can you see if it is correct i am still not getting the workers list

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this

```
$scope.controlOwners[0].worker.fullName = 'Rajasekaran, Shanmuga';
```